# Issue when trying to display data with the help of pagination in list and grid view in Vuejs?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

https://codepen.io/santoshch/pen/wvJBjKq

```js
//grid and list view code
<div class="bar">
<a class="list-icon" v-bind:class="{ 'active': layout == 'list'}" v-on:click="layout = 'list'"></a>
<a class="grid-icon" v-bind:class="{ 'active': layout == 'grid'}" v-on:click="layout = 'grid'"></a>
     
 </div>

<ul v-if="layout == 'grid'" class="grid">
    <!-- A view with big photos and no text -->
    <p>a</P>
  <p>b</p>
    <p>c</P>
  <p>c</p>
  <p>e</P>
  <p>f</p>  <p>g</P>
  <p>h</p>  <p>u</P>
  <p>z</p>
    
  </ul>

   <ul v-if="layout == 'list'" class="list">
   <p>83</P>
  <p>27</p>
   <p>526</P>
  <p>131</p>
  <p>11</P>
  <p>3</p>  <p>1</P>
  <p>5</p>  <p>2</P>
  <p>3</p>
</ul>
```

```html
<template>
 //pagination code
 <div class="overflow-auto">
    <b-pagination
      v-model="currentPage"
      :total-rows="rows"
      :per-page="perPage"
      aria-controls="my-table"
    ></b-pagination>

    <p class="mt-3">Current Page: {{ currentPage }}</p>

    <b-table
      id="my-table"
      :items="items"
      :per-page="perPage"
      :current-page="currentPage"
      small
    ></b-table>
  </div>
</template>
```

I have grid and list view functionality  and i am successfully able to toggle between them and see the data, Now the issue is

When toggling i have some data in grid and list view, So now i want to Show only limited data with the help of pagination
i.e, In grid view as 12 items and list as 8 items.

This is my working codepen link. https://codepen.io/santoshch/pen/wvJBjKq

Answer (score 0):

you need a decent data array for your items you want to show.
like if you only want to show 12 items in grid view then you should make sure when using `v-for` you just looping 12 times in grid and 8 times in list.

```html
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <ul v-if="layout === 'grid'" class="grid-view">
      <li
        v-for="item in items.slice(
          pagination.grid.start,
          pagination.grid.limit
        )"
        :key="item.id"
        class="grid-item"
      >
        <img :src="item.imageSrc" />
      </li>
    </ul>
    <ul v-if="layout === 'list'" class="list-view">
      <li
        v-for="item in items.slice(
          pagination.list.start,
          pagination.list.limit
        )"
        :key="item.id"
        class="list-item"
      >
        {{ item.label }}
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "App",
  data: () => ({
    layout: "list",
    pagination: {
      grid: {
        limit: 12,
        start: 0,
      },
      list: {
        limit: 8,
        start: 0,
      },
    },
    items: [
      { id: 1, imageSrc: "https://ur-img-url", label: "lorem ipsum1" },
      { id: 2, imageSrc: "https://ur-img-url", label: "lorem ipsum2" },
      { id: 3, imageSrc: "https://ur-img-url", label: "lorem ipsum3" },
      { id: 4, imageSrc: "https://ur-img-url", label: "lorem ipsum3" },
      { id: 5, imageSrc: "https://ur-img-url", label: "lorem ipsum3" },
      { id: 6, imageSrc: "https://ur-img-url", label: "lorem ipsum3" },
      { id: 7, imageSrc: "https://ur-img-url", label: "lorem ipsum3" },
      { id: 8, imageSrc: "https://ur-img-url", label: "lorem ipsum3" },
      { id: 9, imageSrc: "https://ur-img-url", label: "lorem ipsum3" },
      { id: 10, imageSrc: "https://ur-img-url", label: "lorem ipsum3" },
      { id: 11, imageSrc: "https://ur-img-url", label: "lorem ipsum3" },
      { id: 12, imageSrc: "https://ur-img-url", label: "lorem ipsum3" },
    ],
  }),
};
</script>
```

you need to use the `pagination` data `start` and `limit`. like on page two inside grid view you are on `start: 12` and `limit: 24` simple both are +12

Comment: In my case, I am showing the data in the <ul> <p>a</p></ul>. So in this case is there any alternatives. Because from data i am not getting any values.

Comment: @ganeshc so you hard code your data inside your template?

Comment: Yes i have hard coded the data in the list and grid.

Comment: @ganeshc apart from that this is a very bad idea, i try to update that for you.

Comment: @ganeshc bro that makes no sense at all. if you only want to display 8 items in list view then just hard code 8 items into it. 
the way without a data source is wrong in so many ways.
please try to stick to my example. it makes no sense bulding a pagination otherwise and is nearly impossible to make a good one

Comment: You are  right i am agreeing, But in my case Api is not ready. So in mean while, I am hard coding the data and displaying in the static way. to explore the tecnology.

And i curious to know, How can it be done in the Hard coded way.

If Possible can you please edit my codepen It will be very much help full to me.
https://codepen.io/santoshch/pen/wvJBjKq

Thanks

Comment: if the api is not ready, act like it is and use mocks.
what i did is exactly that, i used a mock data.
try to stick on what i did and add it into your code